# Detect digitally time stretched audio made back to tape

Tags: frequency-spectrum, quantization

Does anyone know how to detect and quantify a digitally time stretched audio signal when made back to tape?

Comment: You could perhaps try and use a phase vocoder which might reveal some noticeable artifacts. Also it's highly unlikely that the effects of quantization would be preserved on tape (an analog medium).

Comment: If you don't have the original to compare to, and if the time-stretching product is really good (like Melodyne or Serato or SoundToys SPEED), it's gonna be real hard to tell it was stretched.  (I presume you mean time-scaled without changing pitch.)  A time-domain time stretcher will have artifacts for note onsets and dissonant chords or many instruments playing many notes simultaniously.

Comment: What does *"quantization of the signal"* mean in the context of this question?

Comment: > If you don't have the original to compare to, and if the time-stretching product is really good (like Melodyne or Serato or SoundToys SPEED), it's gonna be real hard to tell it was stretched. (I presume you mean time-scaled without changing pitch.) A time-domain time stretcher will have artifacts for note onsets and dissonant chords or many instruments playing many notes simultaniously. The time-stretching was most probably done in Pro-tools, and the tapes contain speech not music. And yes, I mean time-scaled without pitch change. > What does "quantization of the signal" mean in the context